# Show manim video in jupyter lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, manim

I'm trying to use manim in jupyter lab.
I can't see the video in jupyter lab.
For example, when I want to run the manim tutorial: https://try.manim.community/
in jupyter lab, I end up with what's on the attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZoLQ.png).

I've installed manim and even jupyter-manim, but nothing works.
Do you have any ideas for solving the problem?

I read the [documentation](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.utils.ipython_magic.ManimMagic.html#manim.utils.ipython_magic.ManimMagic.manim) but but haven't found anything to help me

Thanks

Comment: Did you install the required dependencies (which vary depending on your OS and installation method) ? In particular, did you install ffmpeg ?

Comment: thanks for your help, it was ffmpeg !